# Jira JQL that returns date of status change

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying to use JQL to measure cycle times (the Control Chart has other issues), so I need to get the date that an issue changed status.  I see that one can use the CHANGED keyword to *filter* issues that have changed status on certain dates, but I see no way to actually list the date of the change as a column.

Any ideas?  How would you guys address this lack of visibility into cycle time data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no simple solution available in JIRA at the moment. See the issue https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-12825 for the whole discussion. The argumentation of Atlassian is the following:

- There exists a product [Service Desk](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/service-desk) that implements the SLA feature expressed here.
- There are reports and additional plugins available that give similar information to this. See the [JIRA Suite Utilities](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.googlecode.jira-suite-utilities) which give you a UI for each issue to see the transition summary.
- JQL (JIRA Query Language) was intended to select all issues that match a query, not to select special information to these issues. You have to use the configuration of the table, if it is included there as a field of the issue (which it is not).

Comment: Thanks, @mliebelt for the detailed answer.  Yeah, that's what I want to do - buy ANOTHER product from them to get a simple piece of info on a field that they encouraged me to use!  Anyway, luckily we've switched from Kanban to Scrum in the meantime, but I maintain that Jira completely sucks for Kanban - I could never figure out a way to get decent metrics on my team members.

Comment: I use the Kanban board of JIRA all the time, but for my personal Kanban process. There it fits much better than Scrum, because I can control the load on myself. I don't care about the metrics, though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestions from mliebelt there is another at https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/128370/how-to-capture-date-of-state-change-in-jira. It requires JIRA Misc Workflow Extenstions and uses the "Copy value from field to field" function to capture the transition date in a custom field.

Comment: Thanks, @wayne-johnston - nice to know another way.  Crazy that Jira supports Kanban so poorly out of the box - so clear that they are very scrum-biased.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin in Atlassian Marketplace called [Time in Status](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.obss.plugin.time-in-status/server) just for that purpose. The plugin prepares a report on how much time each issue spent on each status or assignee.

Answer (score 0):

Time in status is useless if need to count of Jiras that changed status on that day. Time in status widgets is useless for this

Comment: The answer is not answering the question.